# How to add new line character in sms using gammu/wammu

Tags: php, sms, sms-gateway, gammu

I have made a custom script in PHP and I am using gammu/wammu to send sms, but I am unable to figure out how to add new line character in SMS.

I have tried

- `\n`
- `\r`
- `\t`
- `0x0a`
- `0x0d`
- `&10;`

but none of these worked.

Comment: Also make sure you are using the correct quotes: `"\r\n"` vs `'\r\n'`.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `\r\n`? It looks to me like SMS needs both a Carriage Return and Line Feed. Another place I looked at said to use `%0a%0d`, which may work, but it seems to be their service rather than everything. I'd give it a try though. Either way, you need to make sure that the `0x0A` and `0x0D` (two characters in hex) get passed to the service sending the SMS.

See [here](http://blog.mobivity.com/?p=147) for the site I mentioned that said `%0a%0d`, it also has a chart of the SMS character set.

Answer (score 0):

I can't get this to work in gammu-smsd either, I really need to be able to send a true newline bytecode in an sms as well.  I've googled for days, searched the gammu codebase. I can't tell if/where it's being trapped but nomatter how I enter in into my sqlite3 gammu-smsd, it's not a newline that comes out at the other end (machine2machine sms).

I don't need a CR/LF, I just need to send a template with \n after a variable string template, using it in an sms based tracker

Update, I figured out a way to make it send what I want.  Since I'm using an sqlite3 database with gammu, this little PHP program makes me send the message to the mobile asset and it gets accepted there:

```
$sms_template=<<<EOD
insert into outbox ( TextDecoded , DestinationNumber, DeliveryReport, CreatorID) values ('%s','%s','yes','auto');
EOD;
$number=1243456;
$terminator=sprintf("%s",chr(10));
$db = new SQLite3("/var/spool/gammu/smsd.sqlite");
$sms='SRV=12171%s';
$sql=sprintf($sms_template, sprintf($sms, $terminator), $number);
$db->exec($sql);
```

That actually stores the sms fine in the outbox and a true newline arrives at the destination.  Really hope this helps someone.  This code is stripped from private stuff, might not work exactly as displayed, but I use a script alike that works.

Glenn

Answer (score 0):

Even though this question was asked ages ago, i thought i might add this as a reference.

Through my testing i found that it depends on the quotes you use. Use " (double quotes) instead of single for it to format the message properly and use \n or \r.

Hope this helps.

Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe quite late with an answer but as a reference that worked perfectly for me:

```
echo -e "Hello\nWorld" | gammu ....
```